# How to find proper MTU size for FTTH EPON?

Tags: linux, gigabit-ethernet, mtu, fiber

I've recently moved to a ISP that provides a 4mbps connection through FTTH(Single OFC). There is a EPON ONU in my premise from which a RJ-45 lan cable is connected to my Intel DH67CL1 board based PC. manual says, the NIC is a gigabit ethernet card. I tried setting **MTU of 8996** and I can ping and browse fine. But, I'm totally in dark whether this value is optimum and works flawlessly browsing sites. How to find and set the proper MTU for a fibre network like this? Is the value correct? Please bear with me, I'm clueless regarding MTU values!

I tried like this decreasing mtu value:

```
:~$ ifconfig eth0 mtu 8997
:~$ SIOCSIFMTU: Invalid argument
```

then with,

```
:~$ ifconfig eth0 mtu 8996
```

^^^ No error message and it seems accepting.

BTW, from arch wiki, I saw that the driver module(e1000e which is used here) used by NIC  have some bug report filed wr.to Jumbo frame. Am I doing things correctly? Earlier MTU was at default 1500. Please guide. thank you

> Some drivers will prevent lower C-states
>   Some kernel drivers, like e1000e will prevent the CPU from entering C-states under C3 with >non-standard MTU sizes by design. See bugzilla #77361 for comments by the developers.
>   [MTU, Jumbo frames](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Jumbo_frames#Notes_on_jumbo_frames)

Comment: You can always try pinging something with the Don’t Fragment flag set and using various payload sizes.

Comment: @DanielB simple answer please. I want to know whether setting MTU to such high values instead of 1500 helps with speed and other factors.